# Как разобраться с мистикой?)) Не знаю как сделать подходящий заголовок)

Tags: java, android, view, камера, android-camera

Такая ситуация... Я вывожу изображение с камеры в `AutoFitTextureView` это кастомная вью которая принимает картинку для показа

вот код

```
public class AutoFitTextureView extends TextureView {

private int mRatioWidth = 0;
private int mRatioHeight = 0;

public AutoFitTextureView(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

public AutoFitTextureView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}

public AutoFitTextureView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

/**
 * Sets the aspect ratio for this view. The size of the view will be measured based on the ratio
 * calculated from the parameters. Note that the actual sizes of parameters don't matter, that
 * is, calling setAspectRatio(2, 3) and setAspectRatio(4, 6) make the same result.
 *
 * @param width  Relative horizontal size
 * @param height Relative vertical size
 */
public void setAspectRatio(int width, int height) {
    if (width < 0 || height < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Size cannot be negative.");
    }
    mRatioWidth = width;
    mRatioHeight = height;
    requestLayout();
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    int height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
    if (0 == mRatioWidth || 0 == mRatioHeight) {
        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
    } else {
        if (width < height * mRatioWidth / mRatioHeight) {
            setMeasuredDimension(width, width * mRatioHeight / mRatioWidth);
        } else {
            setMeasuredDimension(height * mRatioWidth / mRatioHeight, height);
        }
    }
}
}
```

На одном устройстве `Samsung S5` эта картинка получается идеальной

вот фото

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А на `Meizu MX5` и еще одном китайце эта картинка получается на половину экрана

вот так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я попробовал вывести высоту экрана устройства и высоту `AutoFitTextureView` после его создания на двух устройствах

Вот так я получаю высоту `AutoFitTextureView` после его создания

```
final AutoFitTextureView autoFitTextureView = (AutoFitTextureView) findViewById(R.id.autoFitTextureView);
    autoFitTextureView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.e(MY_LOG, "!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! autoFitTextureView " + autoFitTextureView.getHeight());
        }
    });
```

и вот так я получаю высоту экрана

```
/**
 * get a height of the screen
 **/
public static int getHeight(Activity act) {
    DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    act.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
    return displaymetrics.heightPixels;
}
```

показатели такие

на `Samsung S5`:

> E/CameraActivity: !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! getHeight() 1920
>
> E/CameraActivity: !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! autoFitTextureView 1920

и на `Meizu MX5` вот так

> E/CameraActivity: !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! getHeight() 1920
>
> E/CameraActivity: !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! autoFitTextureView 1920

Это означает, что на устройствах одинаковые по высоте экраны и `AutoFitTextureView` что на одном что на другом устройстве растягивается одинаково на весь экран...

Почему тогда на `Samsung` картинка как положено а на `Meizu` и еще одном китайце картинка на пол экрана???

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Мне кажется, на первый взгляд, что проблема не в том, что картинка на половину экрана, а в каких то дефолтных параметрах, которые отвечают за "вписываемость" контента в границы виджета на этих устройствах, которые отличаются от принятых в андроид. То есть, на первом скриншоте заполнение по высоте (чтобы вошло 100% высоты, а по ширине обрезано), на втором - по ширине (чтобы вошло 100% ширины, а высота соответственно пропорциям.).

Comment: Только, что померял ширину экрана и ширину `AutoFitTextureView` она одинакова 1080... Так я не до конца понял, исходя из ваших слов куда смотреть нужно? Как это померять чтоб на цифрах увидеть в чем разница? а то так получается, что все одинаково, а по факту нет...

Comment: Ну вот если вы в виджет `ImageView` поместите изображение, которое больше чем размеры виджета, то там есть множество значений параметра crop, как его туда уместить: по центру без изменения размера (что войдет в окошко, остальное обрезать), целиком по вертикальной оси, целиком по горизонтальной, по любой оси, но чтобы вошло все изображение и тд. - здесь возможно то же самое происходит.

Comment: @pavlofff аа я понял... Но у меня есть конкретный кастомный класс, который должен работать для всех одинаково... Странно конечно получается...

Comment: Ну это же не ваш класс, а унаследованный от `TextureView` и вы переопределили только очень малую часть всей его функциональности. Все сказанное мной только предположение, просто по скриншотам очень похоже, что происходит именно это.

Comment: @pavlofff Ну да вы правы,  нужно проверить... Если я правильно понял вы думаете,  что на девайсах по разному транслируются изображения по отношению к ввсоте и ширине и поэтому по разному обрезаются?